# How to hide a file in public area of the iOS app

Tags: xcode, hidden-files

I need to remove file (file contains cert string) from package, which now is in public content. After exporting my app from iTunes I can see (using show package contents option) a lot of graphics files and a file which should not be availiable to see. If I added file to Compile Sources then is not readable.

Is there any option to hide files from a package?

Comment: Should a content of file be downloaded and stores in database ?